# Can we use Apple Watch sensors all day long with no limit?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, apple-watch, watchos

I'm student from Korea. I'm interested in apple things.

I have several questions about Apple Watch sensors such as ECG(Electrocardiogram), Heart rate, Oxygen Saturation, breath rate, atrial fibrillation(afib) and so on.

First of all, Can I use these sensors all day long? with no limit?

I'm planning to develop some healthcare application using Apple Watch with sensors.

I can't find examples of using sensors 24/7.

And Second, If I can use the sensors all day long, can I execute the app in background?

Finally, If I can execute the app in background, can I activate the sensors in background?

Thank you for your help.

I have tried searching developer guide, and searching the GitHub.

Comment: I haven't used HealthKit before. You should read Apple's HealthKit documentation. You will need to ask the user for permission to collect and view health data. It looks like you can set up your app to collect "Workout" data, which lets it record health data from the background." You will quickly run down the battery on a watch if you try to collect ECG data constantly. You will need to collect samples of data on some interval (for example, record a few seconds of ECG data every minute.)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Likely not but if you are affiliated with medical research Apple has special programs, look into ResearchKit